# What kind of index(es) would be best to create to be able to search by one field and sort by another

Tags: mongodb

I have a big collection of many million records consisting of:

```
{
    "id1":string,
    "id2":string,
    "correlation":number
}
```

Which represents the relationships between pairs of records.
I would like to be able to efficiently run such queries as

```
db.collection.find({id1: 1}).sort({correlation: -1})
```

So, getting records by field id1 and sorting them by correlation field (in the descending order).

What kind of index(es) would be the most appropriate for such scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the solution is to create the compound index like the following:

```
db.collection.createIndex({"id1": 1, "correlation": -1})
```

In my case all the queries of the form

```
db.collection.find({id1: id}).sort({correlation: -1})
```

run almost instantaneously.